# Importing Python Package from another folder

Tags: python, package, python-import

I have seen many questions and answers for this same, but none of them solved mine. Please have a look into this,

This is my folder structure,

```
code/ 
  helloworld.py
stdlib/
  stdio.py
  stddraw.py 
  __init__.py
```

Inside __init.py i have done

```
from . import stdio
```

Inside helloworld.py, i have done

```
from ..stdlib import stdio
stdio.writeln("Test")
```

But it says me an error saying, "**attempted relative import with no known parent package**"
Can anyone please explain me what i am doing wrong in this case?

Comment: This question [(Importing files from different folder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: as @wangonya suggested, you should make a parent package and add a __init__.py file.
After that you should import like this: ```from stdlib import *```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you would need a "parent package" for what you're currently doing to work. Something like this:

```
parent/
 __init__.py
 code/ 
  helloworld.py
 stdlib/
  stdio.py
  stddraw.py 
  __init__.py
```

Comment: I have done this, but it also doent seem to work

Comment: I like to call a function from stdio.py inside helloworld.py. I believe i should have explained this first. Apologies

Comment: Where are you running the script from? This might not work if you run the script outside of `parent`

Comment: My executable is helloworld.py file

Comment: Is the error being shown on a console when you try to run the script or on a text editor?

Comment: Does running `python helloworld.py` on a console work (despite the vscode error)?